# create a web page with drag and drop to work on PC, iPad & iPhone

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iphone, ipad, drag-and-drop

Is it possible or easy to create a web page that allows users to drag and drop divs around the screen, and that this would work in a brwoser, whether that is on a PC, and iPhone, or an iPad?

My web page uses a few divs which contain some content, and the user is able to move these around as they wish.

It is currently created using ASP.NET DragPanelExtenders, but if they have to be abandoned, so be it.

To get this workign, will I have to create two versions of the page: one for PC based on mousemove events, and one for iPhone/iPad based on touch events?

Answer (score 0):

One option is jQtouch.  http://www.jqtouch.com/

http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html  Also explains how to do drag and drop on webkit based browsers (iphone, ipad, android, ...)  You could write some code to see if your page is running on a computer or a phone, and use the linked code if on a phone.